# Ajax передача переменной

Tags: ajax

Как мы знаем, в param можно передать данные из формы методом `serialize`.
Так же можно передать и так: `{"name": data}`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'action.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: param,
   success:function(data){}
})
```

В таком случае обработчик принимает `$_POST[serialize]` или `$_POST["name"]`.

Подскажите: как в js (ajax) а именно в место param динамически передать свою переменную? То есть этот ajax у меня в функции, которую я вызываю несколько раз и мне нужно в место param что бы были мои подставленные значения, например: передать var test и тогда в обработчике мы должны принять `$_POST["test"]`.

Сочинял долго, надеюсь понятный вопрос.

Comment: Не совсем ясно, что мешает её передать как data: {"test": test}?

Comment: Как мне в место "test" поставить своё значение, которое хранится только в переменной?

Comment: @Владимир: О чём вы?  `var foo = 'foo text'; console.log({test : foo});` или `var params = {bar : 'bar text'};  params['test'] = foo;  console.log(params);`

Comment: Ничего не выходит

Answer (score 1):

такую функцию можно использовать для передачи данных из нужного вам места

```
var myAjax = function(data){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'action.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success:function(data){}
   });
}
```

можно и так

```
var myAjax = function(param, value){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'action.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {param: value},
      success:function(data){}
   });
}
```